# Forcing Logo to stay in line with Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, alignment

I'm trying to get my Logo, to stay in line with the Menu.

Example:

```
_________________|<Edge of logo------|____________________________________
_________________|<Edge of Menu ---------------------------|_______________
```

The 2 edges should line up regardless of page size.

Currently, when the page is re-sized, the items separate and move about independently.

Here is a link to the site: goo.gl/46yUrt

Let me know if you need any other info.

[Edit 1]

header.php Code: (not sure if this has anything to do with the independent alignments, but I've included it anyways)

```
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
<div class="logo-align">
                <a href="http://level42.ca/village"><img src="http://level42.ca/village/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/logo.png" width="370" height="61" alt="© FDC Designs"></a><P></P>
            </div>
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h3>
                    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </div><!-- #navbar -->
```

Style.css code:

```
/**
 * 4.2 Navigation
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1028px;
    min-height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    /*float:right;
    Padding: 0 300px;*/
    z-index: 1;
    top: 30px;
    Background: #141412;
}
```

Logo Alignment:

```
.site-header .logo-align {
     padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
     position: relative;
     left: 20%;
}
```

I'm no CSS expert, a complete noob at best. I've tried adding left: 25%, which seems to work, but only as long as I don't change the page size. I've played around with Padding, Positing, and float commands, but I can't seem to line them up properly.

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed because as soon as you've fixed the problem the question becomes useless for anyone having the same problem later. For instructions on how to improve the question see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I've added some more detail, I'm not entirely sure what Code snippets may be needed to show you guys the problem, but these are the code lines I use to move around the menu and logo. My knowledge of CSS is very minimal. I'm kinda learning as I go. If there's something else you'd need, or feel I should include, please let me know.

Comment: Why does this question have a negative 1? I've added all required information, to the best of my ability, and I'm willing to add more information as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Mariano Urbonas, instead of having the code like so:

```
<div class="logo-align">
          Logo
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
     <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
          Nav Bar
     </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div>
```

And trying to align each element individually, I've changed the header.php code as follows: adding both elements to 1 div.

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
     <div class="logo-align">
          Logo
     </div>
     <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
          Nav Bar
     </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div>
```

In doing so, I was able to add this to `<div id="navbar" class="navbar">` and it seems to align them correctly at any size.

```
background-color: #ffffff;
margin: auto;
max-width: 1028px;
width: 100%;
```

I was required to also remove the independent alignment code I wrote earlier.

From `<div class"logo-align">`

```
 left: 20%;
```

From `<nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">`

```
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
```

In doing these changes, it seems to work as I have expected it.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting both logo and menu inside same div or even a  tag and apply a left margin to it.. I dont fully understanf how your page is built

Comment: The theme I've made was based on the default Wordpress "TwentyThirteen" theme, I've just been chipping away at the code till it looks somewhat like what I have in mind.

Adding the logo inside the div in the header.php file?

I'm toying with that now, I will post my results if I can get this to line up.